# Seeking a ByteArrayInputStream using java.io

Tags: java, io, stream, nio

How can I seek (change the position) of a `ByteArrayInputStream` (`java.io`)? It is something so obvious, but I can't seem to find a method for this anywhere (`mark`/`reset` is not enough, I need to set the position to anywhere on the `InputStream`).

If it can't be done using `java.io` and I must switch to `java.nio` and use a `ByteBuffer`, how can I get something similar to a `DataOutputStream` wrapping a `ByteArrayOutputStream` using `java.nio`? I'm not finding any kind of auto-resizable buffer.

**EDIT:** I've found one way to achieve what I'm attempting to do, but it's a bit messy. `ImageIO.createImageInputStream` creates a `ImageInputStream`, which is exactly what I want (can seek and read primitives). However, using a `ByteArrayInputStream` returns a `FileCacheImageInputStream`, which basically means it copies the byte array to a file just to seek.

This is my first time trying to use the Java IO classes and it has been completely negative. It's missing some fundamental (IMO) features, and it has lots of ways to do the same thing (e.g. to read primitives from a file you can either use `RandomAccessFile`, `DataInputStream` + `FileInputStream`, `FileImageInputStream`, `FileChannel` + `ByteBuffer`, and maybe even more).

Comment: do you see any problem with using `seek`?

Comment: @Vilay Mathew : What `seek` method? I don't see any on ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: File i/o in java is a huge mess.  I teach it to first-year students and try to make it simple, but it's always a point of confusion.

Answer (score 13):

You'd use `reset()`/`skip()`. I can't say it's the nicest API in the world, but it should work:

```
public void seek(ByteArrayInputStream input, int position)
    throws IOException
{
    input.reset();
    input.skip(position);
}
```

Of course, that assumes that no-one has called `mark()`.

Comment: if mark is not called then default value of marked position is 0 hence calling reset moves the pointer to 0 and then skip function moves the pointer to the given position

Comment: @SumitKumarSaha: Yes... I'm not sure of the point of your comment.

Comment: I was just adding up on your answer

Answer (score 6):

If you are creating the `ByteArrayInputStream` to pass elsewhere, extend the class and manipulate `pos` (a `protected` member of `ByteArrayInputStream`) as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`ByteArrayInputStream(byte(), int, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) constructor that will give you an input stream that will read up to a given count of bytes starting from a given offset.  You can use this to simulate seeking to an arbitrary offset in the stream.

You have to deal with the fact that "seeking" gives you a new stream object, and this may be awkward.  However, this approach does not involve copying any bytes or saving them to a file, and it should be safe to not bother with closing the `ByteArrayInputStream` objects.