# Random Access on AudioInputStream java

Tags: java, javax.sound.sampled

Is there an example of randomly accessing an AudioInputStream? something like any ordinary audio player does - when you take the bar wherever you want and it plays from wherever you want, how can i access bytes in the audio stream in that manner?

something simple like that : `read(byte[] buffer, long startingFrom)` where startingFrom can be wherever i want in the audio stream

Comment: Seems unlikely; the whole idea of streams is that you can only read (or write) them from start to finish. It looks like the best you can do with the Java Sound API is read the whole file into memory (eg a byte array), then play it back from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using (simulating?) random access in an `AudioInputStream` is the same as in a normal `InputStream`. You can create a [`mark()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#mark-int-) at the beginning of the file, so before any calls to `read()` have been done. Then, when you want to do random access, you stop reading from the stream, go to the marker position by calling [`reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#reset--) and then use [`skip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#skip-long-) to go to the location you desire.

Note that the initial 'mark' will default to 0 for an `AudioInputStream`, so the initial call is not needed. However this behavior is not specified so it might change in the future.

The implementation of `AudioInputStream` (Oracle Java 8) supports this mechanism if the underlying stream (for instance the `InputStream` you give to the constructor) supports it. You can find if the `AudioInputStream` supports it by calling [`markSupported()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#markSupported--).

Unfortunately when using the utility functions from `AudioSystem` to create the `AudioInputStream` you can't influence the underlying stream. It could even differ per platform. If your stream does not support it (or you want to be absolutely sure it does support it) you could create a new `AudioInputStream` by wrapping one in a `BufferedInputStream`. For example like this:

```
AudioInputStream normalStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(...);
AudioInputStream bufferedStream = new AudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(normalStream),
                                    normalStream.getFormat(), AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED);
```

Disclaimer: I would qualify this has a 'hack' to create random access. <strike>To my surprise I could find little about simulating random access using the mark/reset mechanism in `InputStream`. This might be because there is a caveat to it.</strike> Edit: [John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792757/137369) agrees with me on this approach.